# Change UX and guidance when trying to self delete question with answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-questions

If you attempt to delete a question which has answers, you first see:

> [image]

Clicking "Delete Question" pops up the following error banner:

> [image]

This is problematic for two reasons. First, the "you can't do this" should appear when you first click "Delete" and not after "Delete-->Delete Question--> jk you can't."

Second, it provides users guidance to flag for a moderator to delete it. However, in many (most?) cases moderators actually do not delete questions in situations like this, even though the guidance explicitly calls it out.

My recommendation is to just remove the second half of this prompt. It would be nice to have better guidance, too, but the easiest solution is to just make the prompt say, "Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted."

Comment: It should probably recommend *editing* as an alternative to deletion.

Comment: Those are two different messages on two different levels. The first is not blocking, just a "friendly tip", which also doesn't check the answers score as far as I know. The second is the actual server side validation, checking for answer score at the time of pushing the button, so it really can't be removed. For example suppose a user spends few minutes on the page, and only then decides to click the "Delete Question" button. In those minutes, an answer got upvoted. What you suggest is that the deletion will fail without any message at all. Not a good idea IMO.

Comment: @ShadowWizard did you not read the suggestion? I am suggesting removing the "flag it for moderator attention instead" part of the second prompt, which doesn't change any functionality for how the validation occurs.

Comment: @CodyGray But then it would also have to point out blanking the question is not an option either!

Comment: Why can't the prompt be "Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted. Please see how [deleting works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/197901)."?

Comment: @Meta'sMug IIRC, you **can** delete a question with answers if none of the answers are +1.

Comment: @EBrown yes. IMO the problem is that the message is telling users to custom-flag for moderator attention, and then the only thing a moderator will do is decline and provide a link to "how deleting works" - the custom flag part is useless.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We've changed the guidance on the red warning message. It now reads the following:

[image: new warning for questions that cannot be deleted 'cause they have upvoted answers]

And that link point to `/help/deleted-questions`, so [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions), on MSE.

That way, we're doing three things:

1. Informing the user that the action cannot be taken;
2. Informing the user *why* the action cannot be taken;
3. Providing a link to more detailed information.

We also considered showing the red warning before the other one, thus reversing the order in which the checks are done, but decided against it: it still makes sense to warn the users on why we *generally* advise against deleting one's own posts, *even if the particular instance at hand can't be deleted*.

Comment: Is this also done on MSE?

Comment: It was, indeed.

Comment: @enderland - do you have a reason to think otherwise?

Comment: @Oded I misunderstood the timing of the guidance. It only appears _after_ the first dialog, I was expecting it to have replaced the first dialog (such as when I try to delete this question :-).